# Javascript revive destroyed object in window

Tags: javascript, object, window

Let's say that I delete a default window object/class/property like:

```
delete window.WebSocket
```

I know I can do:

```
 nw=window.open('');
 WebSocket = nw.WebSocket;
 nw.close();
```

The question is:
is it possible to get the WebSocket object of this example without physically opening and closing a window?
(and without adding an iframe)

Comment: If your question were "I shot myself in the foot, were can I get a new foot?" I'd answer "Just don't in the first place"

Comment: LOL! @JonasWilms :D no.. it's not. I just wish to know if it's possible to get the object somehow from window contructor/prototype/proxy/class/whatnot

Comment: Simple answer is ... no. Can't burn your house down and quickly restore that either

Comment: What is your usecase? Why do you want to remove it from `window` ?

Comment: everything possible except what is strictly needed. It's just a case study.

Comment: for example getting rid of internal native objects but in a way they can't be retrieved by external javascript... this could be useful in many cases.